# Cancel last sent message ZeroMQ (python) (dealer/router and pushh/pull)

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

How would one cancel the last sent message ?

I have this set up

[image]

The idea is that the client can ask for different types of large data.
The server reads the request from the client and answers an acknowledgement.
Once its data is ready, it pushes it through the other socket.
This enables queueing task on the server side when multiple clients are connected.
However, if the client decides that it does not need the data anymore, it can send a cancel message to the server.

I'm using asyncio.Queue for queueing messages, so I can easily empty the queue, however, I don't know how to drop a message that is in the push/pull pipe to free up the channel?

The kill switch example (Figure 19 - Parallel Pipeline with Kill Signaling) in https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/ is used to end the process. I just want to cancel it.

<s>My idea was to close the socket on the server side and reopen it, but even with linger set to 0, the messages are not dropped.</s>

EDIT: The messages are indeed dropped, but I feel the solution is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really make any sense for ZeroMQ itself to have such a feature.

Suppose that it did have a cancel message feature. For it to operate as expected, you would be critically dependent on the speed of the network. You might develop on a slow network and their you have the time available to decide to cancel, submit the request and for that to take effect before anything has moved anywhere. But on a fast network you won't.

ZeroMQ is a bit like the post office. Once you have posted a letter, they are going to deliver it.

Other issues for a library developer would include how messages are identified, who can cancel a message, etc? It would get very complex for the library to do it and cater for all possible use cases, so it's not unreasonable that they've left such things as an exercise for the application developers.

**Chop the Responses Up**

You could divide the responses up into smaller messages, send them at some likely rate (proportionate to the network throughput) and check to see if a cancellation has been received before sending each chunk.

It's a bit fiddly, you'd need to know what kind of rate to send the smaller messages so that you don't starve the network, but don't over do it either.

**Or, Convert to CSP**

The problem lies in ZeroMQ implementing Actor Model, where the transport buffers messages. What you need is Communicating Sequential Processes, which does not buffer messages. You can implement this quite easily on top of ZeroMQ, basically all you need to do is have a two way message exchange going on basically like:

- Peer1->Peer2: I'd like to send you a message
- time passes
- Peer2->Peer1: Okay send a message
- Peer1->Peer2: Here is the message
- time passes
- Peer2->Peer1: I have received the message
- end

And in doing this the peers would block, ie peer 1 does nothing else until it gets peer 2's final response.

This feels clunky, but it's what you have to do to reign in an Actor Model system and control where your messages are at any point in time. It's slower because there's more too-ing and fro-ing going on between the peers (in systems like Transputers, this was all done down at the electronic level, so it wasn't an encumberance on software).

The blocking can be a blessing, if throughput matters. Basically, if you find the sender is being blocked too much, that just means you haven't got enough receivers for the tasks they're performing. Actor Model can deceive, because buffering in the network / actor model implementation can temporarily soak up an excess of messages, adding a bit of latency that goes unnoticed.

Anyway, this way you can have a mechanism whereby the flow of messages is fully managed within the application, and not within the ZeroMQ library. If a client does send a "cancel my last request" message (using the above mechanism to send it), that either arrives before the reponse has started to be sent, or after the response has already been delivered to the client (using the mechanism above to send it). There is no intermediate state where a response is already on the way, but out of control of the applications.

CSP is a mode that I'd dearly like ZeroMQ to implement natively. It nearly does, in that you can control the socket high water marks. Unfortunately, a high water mark of 0 means "inifinite", not zero.

CSP itself is a 1970s idea, that saw some popularity and indeed silicon in the 1980s, early 1990s (Inmos, Transputers, Occam, etc) but has recently made something of a comeback in languages like Rust, Go, Erlang. There's even a MS-supplied library for .NET that does it too (not that they call it CSP).

The really big benefit of CSP is that it is algebraically analysable - a design can be analysed and proven to be free of deadlock, without having to do any testing. However, with Actor model systems you cannot do that, and testing will not confirm a lack of problems either. Complex, circular message flows in Actor model can easily lead to deadlock, but that might not occur until the network between computers becomes just a tiny bit busier. Deadlock can happen in CSP too, but it's basically guaranteed to happen every time, if the system has accidentally been architected to deadlock. This shows up in testing quite readily (so at least you know early on!).

As I alluded to early, CSP also doesn't deceive you into thinking there is enough compute resources in a system. If a sender has a strict schedule to keep, and the recipient(s) aren't keeping up, the sender ends up being blocked trying to send instead of waiting for fresh input. It's easy to detect that the real time requirement has not been met. Whereas with Actor model, the send launches messages off into some buffer, and so long as the receiver(s) on average keeps up, all appears to be OK. However, you have no visibility of whether messages are building up inside the (in this case) ZeroMQ's own buffers, so there is little notice of a trending problem in the overall system.